# Diode in Proteus

Tags: diodes, proteus

I am designing a circuit that has some diodes. And I found a problem. Please take a look on the images and tell me why the 8th pin is at HIGH level?
[image]

Comment: When is it 'high', in picture (2)?

Comment: Why would you expect that it _would not_ be high? Why should it be low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default state of a TTL input, if nothing is actively pulling it low, is high, because of an internal pullup resistor.

With your circuit, even if the switch is closed, the diode prevents pin 3 from pulling pin 8 low.

Just as a side note, it would be more conventional to show your logic flowing from left to right, with the inputs of each function on the left and the outputs on the right.

Comment: An a side question, I have pins A, B and C. I want to connect A and B to C. But I don't want the signal goes from A to B and vice versa. This can be done by a OR gate. But is there any solution? (i think cannot use diode because of the question of this topic)

Comment: Do you want to connect "A AND B" to C or "A OR B" to C? This will determine the gate you need. Diodes are poor imitations of gates; you would only use them in extenuating circumstances.